# Create an attributedString from html content without removing newline character

Tags: ios, swift

I try to create an attribute string from a html response to show it on a label. But, when I created the string, I am facing some issues. The conversion removes the newline characters from the string.

```
let text = "test test test\n\nline 2 test test test\n\nline 3 test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test test"

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.body, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.charcoal, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
```

I want to assign this attributed string to a label. But it doesn't shows the text with line breaks. Please, help me to solve this

Comment: in html new line characters will be removed. what's the reason to keep newline characters

Comment: @Vinodh to show the text in a label with separate lines

Comment: that is done by the NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html what is the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace all `\n` with `<br>`. `<br>` is the html tag for new line. [HTML Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/)

```
var text = "<ol><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li></ol><ul><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li></ul>
            \ntest test test\n\nline 2 test test test\n\nline 3 test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test test"
text = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br>")
lbl.numberOfLines = 0
guard let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
    return
}
do {
    let attributedString = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15), range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
    attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

    lbl.attributedText = attributedString
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

[image]

Comment: the best answer so far. Simple easy quick

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have set proper `constraint` and `numberOfLines` should be zero for `UILable`

**Code (Swift 5.0):**

```
let text = "test test test\n\nline 2 test test test\n\nline 3 test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test test"

let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0),
                            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green]

let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: myAttribute)
lblTitle.attributedText = attributedText
```

[image: Output]

[Download sample code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U7CClQ_nuLNcRVR-Q2ShenaHx9UIoKS1)

Answer (score -1):

Simply create `NSAttributedString` with the text and the required attributes.

```
var text = "test test test\n\nline 2 test test test\n\nline 3 test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test testtest test test test test test"
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .semibold)])
self.label.attributedText = attributedString
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]